# Incorporating a javascript variable in a file path

Tags: javascript

I am developing a page to display an image, dependent on what the user has previously chosen from a menu. The name of the .jpg is passed in as a parameter ('photo') on the URL and I have been able to parse this as a global variable (myphoto). The .jpgs are all held in one folder.

I now need to do something like (I guess) quoting the image source as being

```
"myfolder/"+<script>document.write(myphoto)</script>
```

but this is not working. Any ideas please?

(Image tag changed here to get round the anti-spam.)

BTW all client-side javascript. It's been a few years since I've used this!

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: Just format your code as code (by intending it with four spaces or by using backticks ` ) and it is displayed correctly ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the opposite and output the whole image tag in javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
  document.write('<img src="myfolder/' + myphoto + '" />')'
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Oded
Yes, just tried that and it's worked a treat. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because when the browser sees this line: `<img src="myfolder/"+<script>document.write(myphoto)</script>`, it's treating the + character as a character and not an operator.

You will need to programmatically set the `src` of the image. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = "myfolder/" + myphoto;
```

or with jQuery:

```
$("#myImage").attr("src", "myfolder/" + myphoto);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("imgtagid").src = "your image folder/" + selectedPhoto
```